# Parsing String to JsonObject using GSON gives IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following code:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
System.out.println("gson.toJson: "  + gson.toJson(roomList));
JsonObject json2 = parser.parse("{\"b\":\"c\"}").getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("json2: " + json2);
JsonObject json = parser.parse(gson.toJson(roomList)).getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("json: " + json);
```

It gives me the following output:

```
gson.toJson: [{"id":"8a3d16bb328c9ba201328c9ba5db0000","roomID":9411,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328b9f3a01328b9f3bb80000","roomID":1309,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328ba09101328ba09edd0000","roomID":1304,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bb8af640000","roomID":4383,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bd271fe0001","roomID":5000,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bd2e0e30002","roomID":2485,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bd3087b0003","roomID":6175,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bd35a840004","roomID":3750,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bd366250005","roomID":370,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"},{"id":"402881e4328bb83601328bd3807d0006","roomID":9477,"numberOfUsers":4,"roomType":"BigTwo"}]
json2: {"b":"c"}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Object.
```

Can someone please help me parse my Json string to JsonObject? I have checked in http://jsonlint.com/ that my json is valid though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because due to the JSON structure..
I have to put it into a JSONObject first, like so

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj.addProperty(ServerConstants.JSONoutput, gson.toJson(roomList));
```

Then I would deserialize like

```
 List<RoomData> roomList = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get(CardGameConstants.JSONoutput).toString(), listType);
            for (RoomData roomData : roomList) {
                System.out.println(roomData.getRoomID());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some basic idea.

```
ArrayList<String> roomTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
    roomTypes.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("roomType"));
}
```

Comment: you seem to use json-simple not gson, String constructor on JsonArray is not avail in gson

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that `roomList` is not a `JsonObject` as evident in the printed output. It's actually a `JsonArray`.

To fix the code, call `.getAsJsonArray()` (instead of `.getAsJsonObject()`)

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
System.out.println("gson.toJson: "  + gson.toJson(roomList));
JsonObject json2 = parser.parse("{\"b\":\"c\"}").getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("json2: " + json2);
JsonArray json = parser.parse(gson.toJson(roomList)).getAsJsonArray();
System.out.println("json: " + json);
```